# Optimizing SQL subquery through a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, sql-insert, notin

I want to insert all records from actualEntries table into uniqueEntries table based on actualEntries User_IDs that do not exist in uniqueEntries.

I started with a sql clause containing a `NOT IN` subquery, which is very slow (when operating on 400K records), and turned it into a `LEFT JOIN` clause, but the speed has not improved.

Following is my original sql clause containing the `NOT IN` subquery:

```
INSERT INTO uniqueEntries 
  SELECT * 
  FROM actualEntries 
  WHERE actualEntries.User_ID NOT IN (
    SELECT uniqueEntries.User_ID 
    FROM uniqueEntries
  )
  GROUP BY User_ID"
```

Following is the sql clause after being converted into a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
INSERT INTO uniqueEntries 
  SELECT actualEntries.* 
  FROM actualEntries 
  LEFT JOIN uniqueEntries 
  ON uniqueEntries.User_ID = actualEntries.User_ID 
  WHERE uniqueEntries.User_ID IS NULL 
  GROUP BY User_ID
```

When I run both querys on 50 records they complete right away, but when I run them on 400K records, they don't complete.

What's the quickest way to get this operation done?

**UPDATE / SOLUTION**:
As per @Rahul, @Steve E and @fhthiella I updated the LEFT JOIN as follows, and decreased the processing time to 2 minutes for 470K records.

```
INSERT INTO uniqueEntries 
  SELECT actualEntries.* 
  FROM actualEntries 
  LEFT JOIN uniqueEntries 
  ON uniqueEntries.id = actualEntries.id 
  WHERE uniqueEntries.User_ID IS NULL GROUP BY User_ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all remove the `GROUP BY` clause `GROUP BY User_ID` since it's not needed at all. Moreover, you should be having a index on `User_ID` column for both tables `uniqueEntries` and `actualEntries` since you are using that as join column. with that, your query should look like

```
INSERT INTO uniqueEntries 
  SELECT actualEntries.* 
  FROM actualEntries 
  LEFT JOIN uniqueEntries 
  ON uniqueEntries.User_ID = actualEntries.User_ID 
  WHERE uniqueEntries.User_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: I changed .User_ID on uniqueEntries and actualEntries to .id (that works).
I do need GROUP BY because some entries are duplicates and I only want unique entries

Comment: @xited, still I believe you don't need `GROUP BY` cause the where statement `WHERE uniqueEntries.User_ID IS NULL` will do what you are saying.

Comment: @Rahul not exactly http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096ed8/1 on this context the group by is still needed (or better to use a primary key and then use INSERT IGNORE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3131/1

Comment: @Rahul: uniqueEntries does not contain multiple records with the same User_ID, but actualEntries does. GROUP BY should ensure I'm only pulling unique records from actualEntries after removing uniqueEntries from the output, right?

Comment: @xited, then yes you may need a group by; but I would get the grouping result first using group by and then perform a join with unique_entries. Else, use `insert ignore ...` construct.

Answer (score 2):

Put a Unique or Primary Key on uniqueEntries.User_ID. Then

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO uniqueEntries 
  SELECT actualEntries.* 
  FROM actualEntries
```

The IGNORE clause will make MySQL skip errors in the insert process.
This is what [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) says:

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors
>   that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For
>   example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE
>   index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error
>   and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no
>   error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although
>   duplicate-key errors do not.

Comment: Insert Ignore helped with my request partially.

Answer (score 1):

You should add an index on both uniqueEntries.User_ID and actualEntries.User_ID fields:

```
ALTER TABLE uniqueEntries ADD INDEX idx_ue_id (User_ID);
ALTER TABLE actualEntries ADD INDEX idx_ae_id (User_ID);
```

and this should make the join much faster. I also see that you are selecting all table fields:

```
SELECT actualEntries.*
```

but then you are grouping by User_id

```
GROUP BY User_ID
```

I think you are doing it because there might be multiple rows for each User_ID. MySQL allows you to do so, but notice that if there are multiple rows your query will keep just one, but the values that are not grouped will be undetermined (they can belong to any of the grouped rows).

Comment: @fhthiella re multiple rows. That is right, and I don't care which one gets picked, as long as I retrieve unique rows.

Comment: @xited okay so you can use a GROUP BY like this, as long as you know what you are doing ;) but if you want that User_ID of the uniqueEntries be unique, I think you should accept steve e answer as it's more elegant!